# Transforming data so that the range around the median is more accurate

Tags: algorithm, math, random, normal-distribution

Suppose I have some floats that are normal distributed around 0. I need to serialize this into a uint8, but I would like to "give more" of the uint8 to the center of the distribution, and lose resolution around the edges.

For example: `127` would correspond to `0.0` and `255` to `1.0`. But `191` would *not* be `0.5` — instead, it would be something like `0.3` because we're stretching it so that most of the numbers correspond to values near 0.

In practice, I'm actually going to have a random `uint32` being generated and converted to an `float`. But when testing a linear mapping, the extremes (near -1.0 and 1.0) came up too frequently, and I'd like to center this around `0.0`.

I'm aware that I can use the `Box–Muller transform`, but that's actually not suitable here because:

1. We can cap out at -1.0 and 1.0, no need to have an unbounded output.
2. We only have one number to sample from, not two.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *quantile function* (also known as the inverse CDF) maps uniform random numbers in [0, 1] to numbers that follow a distribution (such as the normal distribution).

However, in the case of the [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) there are certain things to know (call the quantile function Q(u) from now on):

- A quantile function ranges from 0 through 1, not from -1 to 1 or from 0 through 255.
- The normal distribution can take on any real number. And in fact, for this distribution, Q(0) and Q(1) will equal infinity.
- The normal distribution's quantile involves the inverse error function. The quantile may or may not be easy to implement depending on whether your programming environment already has an inverse error function available.
- For the reasons above, whenever the input to the quantile function could be 0 or 1, you will have to scale the quantile function to fit your desired range and avoid infinity, say, from [0.001, 0.999] to [0, 255]. An example in pseudocode is below.

```
 for k in 0..255
    c=0.001+(0.999-0.001)*(k*1.0/256)
    print([k, Q(c)]) // print the uint8 value followed by the quantile
 end
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed. Side note: Is there a way to *skew* this function? i.e. to have the same values at 0 and 255 (0.001 and 0.999), but to have 127 instead of being 0.5, have it skewed (say 0.7)?

Comment: You would use the appropriate quantile function for the skewed distribution.  A simple way to do so is to alter the quantile function by mapping its inputs to new inputs as follows: [0, 0.5] to [0, 0.7], and [0.5, 1.0] to [0.7, 1.0].

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the answer of Peter O. that the proper remapping is done by the error function and some scaling is required as one operates on a finite interval. Basically it comes down to remapping the interval [-1,1] onto itself with an s-shaped function. If you want to be close to the Gaussian you take `erf` and the according inverse. But if you only want to get close, you can take any s-shaped function you like.
Some Python examples for forward and backward mappings could be:

```py
def map_fwd( x, s ):
    return  x / np.sqrt( 1 + s**2 * ( 1 - x**2 ) )
 
def map_bwd( y, s ):
    x = np.sqrt( 1 + s**2 ) * y / np.sqrt( 1 + (s * y)**2 )
    return x
```

or

```py
def map_fwd( x, s ):
    return  np.arctanh( np.tanh( s ) * x ) / s

def map_bwd( y, s ):
    x = np.tanh( s * y ) / np.tanh( s )
    return x
```

or some extreme like

```py
def map_fwd( x, m ):
    return  ellipkinc( np.pi * x / 2.0, m ) / ellipkinc( np.pi / 2.0, m )

def map_bwd( y, m ):
    u = ellipkinc( np.pi / 2.0, m ) * y
    phi =  ellipj( u, m )[-1]
    x = phi * 2 / np.pi
    return x
```

where `s` or `m` are parameters to describe the deviation from a linear mapping.
There are infinite possibilities and the choice depends on precision vs computational effort, I guess.

Comment: Thank for you all your examples!